# Rand() statement always giving the same number

Tags: c++, visual-c++

so im trying to make a random number generator that will give me 1, 2 or 3 but for some reason it always give me 3. sorry its in french but i figured it didnt really matter. also tell me if something is missing its my first time posting here.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

RPC choixOrdi()
{
    int min = 1;
    int max = 3;
    int randNum = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
    return convertirRandNum(randNum);
    
}

RPC convertirRandNum(int randNum)
{
    switch (randNum)
    {
    case 1:
        return RPC::Roche;
        break;
    case 2:
        return RPC::Papier;
        break;
    case 3:
        return RPC::Ciseaux;
        break;
    default:
        return RPC::Invalid;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the random is not properly seeded. As current computer cannot generate a true random number, it generates the deterministic pseudo-random number sequence, which has to be initialized by number you choice. It is called seeding. One solution is that you seed the `rand()` by current time using `srand(time(NULL))`. such as:

```
RPC choixOrdi()
{
    int min = 1;
    int max = 3;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randNum = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
    return convertirRandNum(randNum);
    
}
```

There can be more improvement. You can just throw away the C-style random generator, and use `std::random_device`, `std::mt19937` and so on. You can find examples here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

EDIT: As someone else pointed out, seeding rand(time(NULL)) each time when the function is called is really a bad choice, especially when you have multiple clients calls the function simultaneously. If `random_device` is available to you, this can be other workaround:

```
RPC choixOrdi()
{
    int min = 1;
    int max = 3;
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(min, max);
    return convertirRandNum(dist(rd));
}
```

Comment: it's a bad idea to call `srand()` in a function like that. See [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/995714)

Comment: @phuclv Oh yes, however, as there was no place to put srand(), I had no choice. If there is main() function, I suggest OP to call it at the very first line of main() function, and do not call it again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response ! i managed to figure it out, it was a problem in my main function and after some light modifications its working.

Comment: @OlivierVerreault Um… Will you mark this as an answer then?